# get label(s) of selected values of checkboxgroup

Tags: slds

I would like to get the label(s) of the selected values of a checkboxgroup component.

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[{'label': 'Ross', 'value': 'option1'},
                                                         {'label': 'Rachel', 'value': 'option2'},
                                                        ]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="List" default="option1"/>
    <lightning:checkboxGroup aura:id="mygroup"
                             name="checkboxGroup"
                             label="Checkbox Group"
                             options="{! v.options }"
                             value="{! v.value }"
                             onchange="{! c.handleChange }"
                             required="true" />
</aura:component>
```

For this example, is there a way where I can also get the label (Ross, Rachel) when selected.

Comment: If you want to perform action based on Label then you can simply change `option1` to `Ross` and `option2` to `Rachel`. i.e. `<aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[
{'label': 'Ross', 'value': 'Ross'},
{'label': 'Rachel', 'value': 'Rachel'},
]"/>`

Comment: in the `handleChange` method you can use `var changeValue = event.getParam("value");` to get the value, please check also if you can use `var changeValue = event.getParam("label");` to get the label.